# Fill a logging file with varying lines of data

Tags: java, android-studio

My android application receives sensor-acceleration data and a timestamp continously over BLE. By pressing a save-button on my activity, it generates a logging file with the received data. But unfortunately, in the file is only one line of my data which was received at last. But I want to export more lines in my file until I quit by button. This is my relevant code in `onCreate`-method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_interact);

//initialize views
mSaveBtn = findViewById(R.id.save);

//handle button click
mSaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //text for export to file
        mX_Axis = result_X;
        mY_Axis = result_Y;
        mZ_Axis = result_Z;
        mTime = Long.toString(Timestamp);
              
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    //show PopUp for runtime permission
                    requestPermissions(permissions,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
                }
                else{
                    //permissions are accepted, now memory data
                    saveToTxtFile(mX_Axis, mY_Axis, mZ_Axis, mTime);
                }
            }
            else {
                saveToTxtFile(mX_Axis, mY_Axis, mZ_Axis, mTime);
            }
    }
});

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
   switch (requestCode){
   case WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE:{
       if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]
       == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           //permissions accepted, memory data

           saveToTxtFile(mX_Axis, mY_Axis, mZ_Axis, mTime);
       }
       else{
           //permisssions not accepted, show toast
           Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission is required to store data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

   }
   }
}

private void saveToTxtFile(String mX_Axis, String mY_Axis, String mZ_Axis, String mTime) {
//catch current time for dataname
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
        Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());

try{
//path to storage
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
//create folder with name "myProject_BLE-Data"
File dir = new File(path + "/myProject_BLE-Data/");
dir.mkdirs();
//Dataname
String fileName = "myProject_" + timeStamp + ".txt";

File file = new File(dir, fileName);

//FileWriter class to store characters in file
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("  X-Axis      Y-Axis      Z-Axis     State                   Timestamp\n");
bw.write("_______________________________________________________________________________________\n");
bw.write(" ");
bw.write(mX_Axis);
bw.write("    ");
bw.write(mY_Axis);
bw.write("    ");
bw.write(mZ_Axis);
bw.write("    ");
if (NotificationValue [1] == 0x00) {bw.write(     "State: defect          ");}
else if (NotificationValue [1] == 0x01) {bw.write("State: OK              ");}
else if (NotificationValue [1] == 0x02) {bw.write("State nearly defect     ");}
bw.write(mTime);
bw.close();

//show filename and path in toast
Toast.makeText(this, fileName+"is saved to\n" +dir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (Exception e){
//if something goes wrong...
Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This block should be generated for only one time by creating the file:

```
bw.write("  X-Axis      Y-Axis      Z-Axis     State                   Timestamp\n");
bw.write("_______________________________________________________________________________________\n");
```

And this block represents the line with data which I receive continously:

```
bw.write(" ");
bw.write(mX_Axis);
bw.write("    ");
bw.write(mY_Axis);
bw.write("    ");
bw.write(mZ_Axis);
bw.write("    ");
if (NotificationValue [1] == 0x00) {bw.write(     "State: defect          ");}
else if (NotificationValue [1] == 0x01) {bw.write("State: OK              ");}
else if (NotificationValue [1] == 0x02) {bw.write("State nearly defect     ");}
bw.write(mTime);
bw.close();
```

And I need to generate more lines of that data everytime in the same file, when I receive an notification (or generally: everytime when a special event is happened). But I don´t find a way to do that. It generates everytime a new file with only one line. I tried so many. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the FileWriter to append when you create it `FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true)` -- this way the FileWriter will append to the existing file rather than writing over.

Also the button event only fires once - if you want to continuously save data you'll have to set up a loop that runs until you press the button again.

Comment: Thank you so much so far! Do you have a code snippet which demonstrates that? Are can you demonstrate that in my snippet in my question?

Comment: When using a loop, I think I get the problem that the same thing is copied into my file over and over again.  And when I get new data it is not processed because my code is stuck in the loop. Or do I understand this wrong?

Comment: `//FileWriter class to store characters in file
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);`
All you need to do is add the true to the FileWriter constructor call.

Regarding the loop - yes I see your point. You could try using an eventListener design pattern - the button actives the event listener which writes to the file everytime an event that you want to log happens.